# Using Netflix Conductor Orchestration on AWS ECS

Tags: microservices, amazon-ecs, netflix, netflix-conductor

We are currently working on a approach which will work with collaboration of multiple microservices to provide us with solution.

Dataflow example:

[image: Service Dataflow patterns]

These services will be deployed in ECS with ALB in front of it. I want to stitch together a workflow for the system and needed help with the following:

1. We plan to use Route 53 DNS service for the Service Discovery. I know that conductor uses Eureka client for service discovery. Is it possible just to swap out of use DNS based implementation rather than Eureka??
2. Can Conductor be deployed as docker images in an ECS cluster? Can I create this internal to ECS cluster and not deploy it on EC2 servers? Any documentation that will help? Do we maintain Docker Images or we need to create our own?